# Can there exist distinct sets , not both empty , $A,B$ such that $ A \cup B $ is a subset of $A \cap B $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can there exist distinct  sets , not both empty , $A,B$ such that $ A \cup B $ is a subset of $A \cap B $ , I know this cannot happen as per definitions of elements and subset inclusions of set theory , but I think I saw somewhere this kind of thing but cannot exactly recall now , please help .

Answer (score 2):

Well, no. If $A$ and $B$ are distinct, then there exists some $a\in A$ which is not in $B$ (or the other way around). But then $a\in A\cup B$ and $a \notin A\cap B$, so $A \cup B \subset A\cap B$ cannot hold.

Answer (score 0):

Always $A\cap B\subseteq A\cup B$. If also $A\cup B\subseteq A\cap B$ then equality holds.

Combined with the fact that

> $$(A\triangle B)\sqcup (A\cap B)=A\cup B$$

implies that $A\triangle B=\varnothing$, i.e. $A=B$. (here $\sqcup$ means "[disjoint union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union)." and $A\triangle B$ is the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).)

If you have not seen the highlighted formula before, it's very simple, the $A\triangle B$ is the portion of the venn diagram in $A$ and $B$, but not the intersection.